# Is there a tkinter widget to easily display a table (SQLite) in a window (canvas)?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I have a database table (created using the SQLite3 library) and would like to be able to open a new window (in a program that I am writing) which will simply display the contents of the table (*.db) with a scroll bar to the user (perhaps on a grid like you would find in a spreadsheet).

Are there any easy ways of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would use

1. `.grid()` in a `Frame` or
2. multiple `Listbox`es with as many scrollbars as you like.

Comment: the ttk treeview widget is arguably the best choice: http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html